# Pdfbox 3.0.1 "loading font file" Warning Messages

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have built a simple example program to get familiar with Pdfbox. Can someone explain the warnings I am getting and how to resolve them?  I am using java 17 on a Mac.

The following is the basic code:

```
            PDFont font = new PDType1Font(Standard14Fonts.FontName.TIMES_ROMAN);
            PDDocument doc    = new PDDocument();
            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
            content.beginText();
            content.newLineAtOffset(10, 700);
            content.setFont(font, 12);
            content.showText("this is a test   ");
            content.newLineAtOffset(0, -15);
            content.showText("text in new line  ");
            content.endText();
            content.close();
            doc.addPage(page);
            doc.save("/Users/smith/file.pdf");
```

Warning message:

```
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:32 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider loadDiskCache
WARNING: 2 new fonts found, font cache will be re-built
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:32 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider <init>
WARNING: Building on-disk font cache, this may take a while
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:33 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider addTrueTypeFont
WARNING: Could not load font file: /Users/glilienfield/Library/Fonts/LastResort-Regular.ttf
java.io.IOException: Invalid character code 0xD800
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable.processSubtype12(CmapSubtable.java:258)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable.initSubtable(CmapSubtable.java:110)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapTable.read(CmapTable.java:87)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.readTable(TrueTypeFont.java:365)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:165)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:144)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:66)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.addTrueTypeFont(FileSystemFontProvider.java:692)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.scanFonts(FileSystemFontProvider.java:392)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.<init>(FileSystemFontProvider.java:367)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl$DefaultFontProvider.<clinit>(FontMapperImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getProvider(FontMapperImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFont(FontMapperImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:379)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:353)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<init>(PDType1Font.java:127)
    at com.example.pdf_open_box_demo.PdfOpenBoxDemoApplication.main(PdfOpenBoxDemoApplication.java:14)

Dec 31, 2023 3:51:36 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readLookupTable
SEVERE: The expected SubstFormat for ExtensionSubstFormat1 subtable is 7 but should be 1
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:36 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readLookupTable
SEVERE: The expected SubstFormat for ExtensionSubstFormat1 subtable is 7 but should be 1
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:36 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readLookupTable
SEVERE: The expected SubstFormat for ExtensionSubstFormat1 subtable is 7 but should be 1
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:37 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readLookupTable
SEVERE: The expected SubstFormat for ExtensionSubstFormat1 subtable is 7 but should be 1
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:37 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider addTrueTypeFont
WARNING: Could not load font file: /System/Library/Fonts/LastResort.otf
java.io.IOException: Invalid character code 0xD800
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable.processSubtype13(CmapSubtable.java:320)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable.initSubtable(CmapSubtable.java:113)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapTable.read(CmapTable.java:87)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.readTable(TrueTypeFont.java:365)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:165)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:144)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.OTFParser.parse(OTFParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.OTFParser.parse(OTFParser.java:27)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:66)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.OTFParser.parse(OTFParser.java:50)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.addTrueTypeFont(FileSystemFontProvider.java:685)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.scanFonts(FileSystemFontProvider.java:392)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.<init>(FileSystemFontProvider.java:367)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl$DefaultFontProvider.<clinit>(FontMapperImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getProvider(FontMapperImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFont(FontMapperImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:379)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:353)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<init>(PDType1Font.java:127)
    at com.example.pdf_open_box_demo.PdfOpenBoxDemoApplication.main(PdfOpenBoxDemoApplication.java:14)

Dec 31, 2023 3:51:37 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider addTrueTypeCollection
WARNING: Could not load font file: /System/Library/Fonts/NotoSerifMyanmar.ttc
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFDataStream.readUnsignedShort(TTFDataStream.java:154)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFDataStream.readUnsignedShortArray(TTFDataStream.java:188)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readMultipleSubstitutionSubtable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:412)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupSubtable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:263)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupTable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:313)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupList(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:247)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.read(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:102)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.readTable(TrueTypeFont.java:365)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:165)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:144)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeCollection.getFontAtIndex(TrueTypeCollection.java:127)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeCollection.processAllFonts(TrueTypeCollection.java:109)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.addTrueTypeCollection(FileSystemFontProvider.java:665)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.scanFonts(FileSystemFontProvider.java:396)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.<init>(FileSystemFontProvider.java:367)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl$DefaultFontProvider.<clinit>(FontMapperImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getProvider(FontMapperImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFont(FontMapperImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:379)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:353)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<init>(PDType1Font.java:127)
    at com.example.pdf_open_box_demo.PdfOpenBoxDemoApplication.main(PdfOpenBoxDemoApplication.java:14)

Dec 31, 2023 3:51:37 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:37 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:37 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readLookupTable
SEVERE: The expected SubstFormat for ExtensionSubstFormat1 subtable is 7 but should be 1
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:37 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:48 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:48 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:49 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:49 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readLookupTable
SEVERE: The expected SubstFormat for ExtensionSubstFormat1 subtable is 4 but should be 1
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:49 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readLookupTable
SEVERE: The expected SubstFormat for ExtensionSubstFormat1 subtable is 0 but should be 1
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:49 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:49 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readLookupTable
SEVERE: The expected SubstFormat for ExtensionSubstFormat1 subtable is 4 but should be 1
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:49 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readLookupTable
SEVERE: The expected SubstFormat for ExtensionSubstFormat1 subtable is 0 but should be 1
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:49 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readSingleLookupSubTable
WARNING: Unknown substFormat: 0
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:49 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readSingleLookupSubTable
WARNING: Unknown substFormat: 0
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:49 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider addTrueTypeFont
WARNING: Could not load font file: /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/NotoSansOsage-Regular.ttf
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFDataStream.readUnsignedShort(TTFDataStream.java:154)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readSingleLookupSubTable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:345)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupSubtable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:259)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupTable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:313)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupList(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:247)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.read(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:102)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.readTable(TrueTypeFont.java:365)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:165)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:144)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:66)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.addTrueTypeFont(FileSystemFontProvider.java:692)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.scanFonts(FileSystemFontProvider.java:392)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.<init>(FileSystemFontProvider.java:367)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl$DefaultFontProvider.<clinit>(FontMapperImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getProvider(FontMapperImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFont(FontMapperImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:379)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:353)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<init>(PDType1Font.java:127)
    at com.example.pdf_open_box_demo.PdfOpenBoxDemoApplication.main(PdfOpenBoxDemoApplication.java:14)

Dec 31, 2023 3:51:49 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readSingleLookupSubTable
WARNING: Unknown substFormat: 0
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:49 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readSingleLookupSubTable
WARNING: Unknown substFormat: 256
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:49 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider addTrueTypeFont
WARNING: Could not load font file: /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/NotoSansPahawhHmong-Regular.ttf
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFDataStream.readUnsignedShort(TTFDataStream.java:154)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readSingleLookupSubTable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:345)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupSubtable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:259)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupTable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:313)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupList(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:247)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.read(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:102)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.readTable(TrueTypeFont.java:365)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:165)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:144)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:66)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.addTrueTypeFont(FileSystemFontProvider.java:692)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.scanFonts(FileSystemFontProvider.java:392)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.<init>(FileSystemFontProvider.java:367)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl$DefaultFontProvider.<clinit>(FontMapperImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getProvider(FontMapperImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFont(FontMapperImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:379)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:353)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<init>(PDType1Font.java:127)
    at com.example.pdf_open_box_demo.PdfOpenBoxDemoApplication.main(PdfOpenBoxDemoApplication.java:14)

Dec 31, 2023 3:51:49 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider addTrueTypeFont
WARNING: Could not load font file: /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/NotoSansMiao-Regular.ttf
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFDataStream.readUnsignedShort(TTFDataStream.java:154)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFDataStream.readUnsignedShortArray(TTFDataStream.java:188)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readMultipleSubstitutionSubtable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:412)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupSubtable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:263)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupTable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:313)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupList(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:247)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.read(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:102)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.readTable(TrueTypeFont.java:365)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:165)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:144)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:66)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.addTrueTypeFont(FileSystemFontProvider.java:692)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.scanFonts(FileSystemFontProvider.java:392)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.<init>(FileSystemFontProvider.java:367)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl$DefaultFontProvider.<clinit>(FontMapperImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getProvider(FontMapperImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFont(FontMapperImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:379)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:353)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<init>(PDType1Font.java:127)
    at com.example.pdf_open_box_demo.PdfOpenBoxDemoApplication.main(PdfOpenBoxDemoApplication.java:14)

*<REMOVED A BUNCH OF LINES TO REDUCE THE SIZE OF THE POST>*

Dec 31, 2023 3:51:51 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readSingleLookupSubTable
WARNING: Unknown substFormat: 0
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:51 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readSingleLookupSubTable
WARNING: Unknown substFormat: 256
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:51 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider addTrueTypeFont
WARNING: Could not load font file: /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/NotoSansTaiViet-Regular.ttf
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFDataStream.readUnsignedShort(TTFDataStream.java:154)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readSingleLookupSubTable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:345)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupSubtable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:259)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupTable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:313)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupList(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:247)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.read(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:102)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.readTable(TrueTypeFont.java:365)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:165)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:144)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:66)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.addTrueTypeFont(FileSystemFontProvider.java:692)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.scanFonts(FileSystemFontProvider.java:392)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.<init>(FileSystemFontProvider.java:367)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl$DefaultFontProvider.<clinit>(FontMapperImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getProvider(FontMapperImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFont(FontMapperImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:379)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:353)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<init>(PDType1Font.java:127)
    at com.example.pdf_open_box_demo.PdfOpenBoxDemoApplication.main(PdfOpenBoxDemoApplication.java:14)

Dec 31, 2023 3:51:51 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider addTrueTypeFont
WARNING: Could not load font file: /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/NotoSansOldPermic-Regular.ttf
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFDataStream.readUnsignedShort(TTFDataStream.java:154)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupTable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:293)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupList(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:247)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.read(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:102)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.readTable(TrueTypeFont.java:365)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:165)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:144)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:66)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.addTrueTypeFont(FileSystemFontProvider.java:692)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.scanFonts(FileSystemFontProvider.java:392)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.<init>(FileSystemFontProvider.java:367)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl$DefaultFontProvider.<clinit>(FontMapperImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getProvider(FontMapperImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFont(FontMapperImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:379)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:353)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<init>(PDType1Font.java:127)
    at com.example.pdf_open_box_demo.PdfOpenBoxDemoApplication.main(PdfOpenBoxDemoApplication.java:14)

Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readLookupTable
SEVERE: The expected SubstFormat for ExtensionSubstFormat1 subtable is 4 but should be 1
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readLookupTable
SEVERE: The expected SubstFormat for ExtensionSubstFormat1 subtable is 0 but should be 1
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readLookupTable
SEVERE: The expected SubstFormat for ExtensionSubstFormat1 subtable is 4 but should be 1
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readLookupTable
SEVERE: The expected SubstFormat for ExtensionSubstFormat1 subtable is 0 but should be 1
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider addTrueTypeCollection
WARNING: Could not load font file: /System/Library/Fonts/NotoSansKannada.ttc
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFDataStream.readUnsignedShort(TTFDataStream.java:154)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFDataStream.readUnsignedShortArray(TTFDataStream.java:188)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readMultipleSubstitutionSubtable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:412)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupSubtable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:263)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupTable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:313)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupList(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:247)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.read(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:102)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.readTable(TrueTypeFont.java:365)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:165)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:144)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeCollection.getFontAtIndex(TrueTypeCollection.java:127)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeCollection.processAllFonts(TrueTypeCollection.java:109)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.addTrueTypeCollection(FileSystemFontProvider.java:665)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.scanFonts(FileSystemFontProvider.java:396)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.<init>(FileSystemFontProvider.java:367)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl$DefaultFontProvider.<clinit>(FontMapperImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getProvider(FontMapperImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFont(FontMapperImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:379)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:353)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<init>(PDType1Font.java:127)
    at com.example.pdf_open_box_demo.PdfOpenBoxDemoApplication.main(PdfOpenBoxDemoApplication.java:14)

Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:54 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:56 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:56 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:56 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:56 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:56 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable processSubtype14
WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:56 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readLookupTable
SEVERE: The expected SubstFormat for ExtensionSubstFormat1 subtable is 4 but should be 1
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:56 PM org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable readLookupTable
SEVERE: The expected SubstFormat for ExtensionSubstFormat1 subtable is 0 but should be 1
Dec 31, 2023 3:51:56 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider <init>
WARNING: Finished building on-disk font cache, found 760 fonts
done writing pdf file

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I downgraded to PDFBox 2.0.22 and reran after making a minor change to the 'font' declaration (I used the static PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN constant defined in version 2.

I got the following warnings:

```
Dec 31, 2023 3:56:14 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider loadDiskCache
WARNING: New fonts found, font cache will be re-built
Dec 31, 2023 3:56:14 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider <init>
WARNING: Building on-disk font cache, this may take a while
Dec 31, 2023 3:56:16 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider <init>
WARNING: Finished building on-disk font cache, found 778 fonts
done writing pdf file
```

Comment: Please retry with the 3.0.2-SNAPSHOT version, some of these bugs have been fixed.

Comment: See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5743 ; if it still doesn't work, register to JIRA and add the first font that doesn't work. When registering, use a meaningful text (e.g. reference this issue) so we know you're not a spammer. To retry the filling of the font cache, delete the file ".pdfbox.cache" from your home dir.

Comment: I cloned the 3.0 branch and built the 3.0.2-SNAPSHOT and linked the jar to my project. I got the following new error when running the code:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.fontbox.type1.DamagedFontException
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)

Comment: You need to add pdfbox and fontbox and commons-log. Alternatively, use the jar from pdfbox-app.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I did not find the 3.0.2-SNAPSHOT version on maven central.  Are they published somewhere?

Comment: I built the pdfbox-app 3.0.2-SNAPSHOT and used it instead of the PDFBox and font box libraries, as you suggested.  The errors stopped.

Comment: Did you find and delete the file ".pdfbox.cache" before retrying?

Comment: I did.  I got a lot of warnings the first time the program executed, but they did not repeat with subsequent executions. I am all good now. Thanks very much for the help